# Motion Tracking in After Effects looks like it is vibrating

Tags: after-effects

I am newbie to the after effects and I am working on a video. I want to add call outs on a cocktail glass. I am trying motion tracking but not getting the results that I want. I want my base target not to move. It should stay only on one point.

Anybody out there who can help me?

I have attached the screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGw9q.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Motion tracking works best on areas of high contrast.  Maybe the reflections near the rim of the glass are confusing it.  Try tracking from a different part of the glass, eg the base, and see if it works better (you can always use a Null for the track, then parent your objects to that null if the track good but isn't in the exact position you want).

Comment: or you can offset the anchor point.